# how to add tooltip in react d3 v4 bar chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, tooltip, react-component

I have to add the tooltip on react d3 v4 bar chart on mouseover.I have tried customized function mentioned below,

```
onMouseOverHandler(d){
   var tooltip = d3Select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

    tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);      
    tooltip.html(d)  
    .style("left", d3Select(this).attr("cx") + "px")     
    .style("top", d3Select(this).attr("cy") + "px");
```

but it's not working. someone can you help me for this one.

Thanks,
Arun S

Comment: have you looked into tippy.js?  It might help instead of writing it out yourself.

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle or plunker? If we can't reproduce the problem, we can't help you solve it.

Comment: Hi Ryan,I'm just trying to add the tooltip in below mentioned example chart,  https://medium.com/@caspg/responsive-chart-with-react-and-d3v4-afd717e57583 but i'm not sure how to add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added a tooltip to the example you linked to in your comment to [this fork of the original GitHub repository](https://github.com/mattbatman/badass-chart).

I created a `Tooltip` component. Of course, keep in mind that this isn't necessarily the "right" or only way to add a tooltip to a React application that uses D3.

I went through the following steps:

1. Created state in the `Chart` component that tracks the data for which bar, if any, is currently hovered
2. Created `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` events in the `Bars` component to determine which bar has just been hovered or left and pass that up to the `Chart` component to set the new state
3. Passed the state from the `Chart` component back down to a `Tooltip` component I created

The `Tooltip` component looks like this:

```
export default ({hoveredBar, scales}) => {
  const { xScale, yScale } = scales
  const styles = {
    left: `${xScale(hoveredBar.title) - 30}px`,
    top: `${yScale(hoveredBar.value)}px`
  }

  return (
    <div className="Tooltip" style={styles}>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colSpan="2">{hoveredBar.title}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan="1">Bodies</td>
            <td colSpan="1">{hoveredBar.value}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan="1">Year</td>
            <td colSpan="1">{hoveredBar.year}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I used it in the `Chart` component, and tracked the currently hovered bar as state:

```
class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.xScale = scaleBand()
    this.yScale = scaleLinear()

    this.state = {
      hoveredBar: null
    }
  }

  render() {
    const margins = { top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 60 }
    const svgDimensions = {
      width: Math.max(this.props.parentWidth, 300),
      height: 500
    }

    const maxValue = Math.max(...data.map(d => d.value))

    const xScale = this.xScale
      .padding(0.5)
      .domain(data.map(d => d.title))
      .range([margins.left, svgDimensions.width - margins.right])

    const yScale = this.yScale
      .domain([0, maxValue])
      .range([svgDimensions.height - margins.bottom, margins.top])

    return (
      <div className="Chart">
        <svg width={svgDimensions.width} height={svgDimensions.height}>
          <Axes
            scales={{ xScale, yScale }}
            margins={margins}
            svgDimensions={svgDimensions}
          />
          <Bars
            scales={{ xScale, yScale }}
            margins={margins}
            data={data}
            maxValue={maxValue}
            svgDimensions={svgDimensions}
            onMouseOverCallback={datum => this.setState({hoveredBar: datum})}
            onMouseOutCallback={datum => this.setState({hoveredBar: null})}
          />
        </svg>
        { this.state.hoveredBar ?
          <Tooltip
            hoveredBar={this.state.hoveredBar}
            scales={{ xScale, yScale }}
          /> :
          null
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And I set the `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` events in the `Bars` component:

```
export default class Bars extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.colorScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, this.props.maxValue])
      .range(['#F3E5F5', '#7B1FA2'])
      .interpolate(interpolateLab)
  }

  render() {
    const { scales, margins, data, svgDimensions } = this.props
    const { xScale, yScale } = scales
    const { height } = svgDimensions

    const bars = (
      data.map(datum =>
        <rect
          key={datum.title}
          x={xScale(datum.title)}
          y={yScale(datum.value)}
          height={height - margins.bottom - scales.yScale(datum.value)}
          width={xScale.bandwidth()}
          fill={this.colorScale(datum.value)}
          onMouseOver={() => this.props.onMouseOverCallback(datum)}
          onMouseOut={() => this.props.onMouseOutCallback(null)}
        />,
      )
    )

    return (
      <g>{bars}</g>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I have described a solution to the same problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674517/2903711

The result looked [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyjFT.png)